# How do you make multiline text into a hoverable tooltip label?

Tags: html, css, tooltip, multiline

Essentially I want to have underlined text (that might span multiple lines), where you can hover over the underlined text to reveal a tooltip. I figured out how to put multiple lines into the tooltips themselves - it is just the labels that I struggle with.

I am very new to HTML; I used this CSS Tooltip Generator to make these tooltips:
http://www.menucool.com/tooltip/css-tooltip

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
.tooltip {
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    border-bottom:1px dotted #666;
    text-align:left;
}

.tooltip .right {
    min-width:200px; 
    top:50%;
    left:100%;
    margin-left:20px;
    transform:translate(0, -50%);
    padding:10px 20px;
    color:#000000;
    background-color:#EEEEEE;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size:13px;
    border-radius:8px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:99999999;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    box-shadow:0 1px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    visibility:hidden; opacity:0; transition:opacity 0.8s;
}

.tooltip:hover .right {
    visibility:visible; opacity:1;
}

.tooltip .right i {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    right:100%;
    margin-top:-12px;
    width:12px;
    height:24px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.tooltip .right i::after {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    width:12px;
    height:12px;
    left:0;
    top:50%;
    transform:translate(50%,-50%) rotate(-45deg);
    background-color:#EEEEEE;
    box-shadow:0 1px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
</style>
<body style="text-align:left;">

<div class="btn btn-primary tooltip">The thing I want to be able to hover over should have multiple lines and allow for the paragraph to continue as normal. Ideally, the link to hover should be underlining all the lines that are in this div tag thingy. Right now, as you can see, it makes a new paragraph if the div tag thingy doesn't take up the whole line, and it only underlines the bottom-most line.
  <div class="right">
  <p> Help! </p>
  <p> Multiple lines within the tooltips work just fine! </p>
  <p> It's the labels that are messed up! </p>
  <i></i>
</div>
</div>

I want this sentence to still be part of that paragraph above, and it's not! How do I do that?

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with the `display: inline-block` line when styling the `.tooltip`: If an element is displayed as inline-block, it creates a closed block like a paragraph:

[image]

As you can try yourself in this little demo: https://jsfiddle.net/5h2wg4f0/1/ , `inline-block` elements create a block around themselves. What you probably want is `display: inline`, this enables the "I want this sentence..."-line to be part of the same paragraph.

To read more about the display options, I recommend https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

In the end, you would probably have to reposition you tooltip, but that seems like a doable job to me...